# Java - How do i get to have the next Letter from Z to be A?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to have the next letter from `Z` to become `A` but my if else statement is not working properly

```
import java.util.ArrayList; // import the ArrayList class
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> alphabets = new ArrayList<String>(); // Create an ArrayList object
        String getalpha;
        alphabets.add("A");
        String nextalpha;
        String lastchar;
        int charValue;
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 30) {
            getalpha = alphabets.get(x);
            lastchar = getalpha.substring(getalpha.length() - 1);// get last character in alphabets
            if (lastchar != "Z") {
                charValue = lastchar.charAt(0);
                nextalpha = String.valueOf((char) (charValue + 1));// next alphabets    
            } else if (lastchar == "Z") {
                nextalpha = "A";

            }
            getalpha = getalpha + nextalpha;
            alphabets.add(getalpha);
            x++;
            System.out.println(getalpha);
        }
        //   System.out.println(alphabets);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hints: 1) compare char values, 2)  `"A"` is a string literal not a char literal, 3) `nextletter = ((letter - 'A') % 26) + 'A';`

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare Strings with "==" operator since it checks for equal references rather than values. Use the equals function.

```java
String a = "z";
String b = "z";
System.out.println(a==b); // false
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // true
```